# Linq update doesn't work when record is read by compiled query

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

I'm tracing this code step by step and everything looks ok, but changes are not reflected in the database.

In my trace the `q` is not null so `VerifiedBy` is being set. then the `db.SubmitChanges()` executes successfully but I check the database and changes are not taken effect

```
using (DatabaseDataContext db = new DatabaseDataContext())
{
    Question q = _Questions.GetQuestionForEdit(db, Id);
    if (q != null && (q.UserId == User.Id || User.GetClaim("canmoderatequestions") == "1"))
       {
           q.VerifiedBy = "-1";
           db.SubmitChanges();
       }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem. The problem was that my compiled query was not returning the exact type. It was returning an extended class of `Question`